# Swift Google Maps not going under Safe Area

Tags: swift, google-maps, uikit, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using Google Maps SDK on iOS using Swift, and have tried to get the map to go under the safe area, but it always respects the safe area.

I have attached the storyboard setup in the images.

How would I stop respecting the safe area and fill it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: bottom is tied to the superview, are you sure thats not the superview that is tied to safe-area?

Comment: I have safe area relative margins and safe area layout guide both enabled, i have added the image in the question. Should both be changed? Thanks

Comment: Unticking both check boxes (top right, bottom image), didnt fill the bottom of the screen but did go up into the top safe area. Still not working sadly.

Comment: You should try but this is definitely a container constraint problem. If you want to be sure you can use the layout debugger (dont remember the name but its the one that let you see all the view stacked one onto another)